# Prove that if $a+b=2$, then $n \in [0..1], \;a^{(2b)^{n}} + b^{(2a)^{n}}\leq 2$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that

> if $a+b=2$, and $ a,b >0$,  $n \in [0..1]$ then $ a^{(2b)^{n}} + b^{(2a)^{n}}\leq 2$

I asked this question because one of a female student in our class (her MathExchange User ID is NH_HN) proved the above inequality while attempting to solve this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198645/prove-that-if-ab-1-then-forall-n-in-mathbbn-a2bn-b2a). I think the question is interesting and I am curious to know the answer. I posted this question here in the hope that s.o can show me the solution

I have try several value of $n$ between $0$ and $1$. For each value of $n$ I plot a function $f(x) = x^{(2(2-x))^{n}} + (2-x)^{(2x)^{n}}$. It is always less than 2 as the inequality said.

Comment: But before that you need to show your work.

Comment: @Macavity Sorry it is a big mistake. I have deleted my comment. Thank you very much.