# Prove that $\exp{\Big(\frac{2b(1-(2b)^n)}{n(1-2b)}\ln(a)}\Big)+\exp{\Big(\frac{2a(1-(2a)^n)}{n(1-2a)}\ln(b)}\Big)\leq1 $

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction, exponentiation

Inspired by [Prove that if $a+b =1$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a^{(2b)^{n}} + b^{(2a)^{n}} \leq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198645/prove-that-if-ab-1-then-forall-n-in-mathbbn-a2bn-b2a?noredirect=1&lq=1) I propose :

> > Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
> >     $$\exp{\Big(\frac{2b(1-(2b)^n)}{n(1-2b)}\ln(a)}\Big)+\exp{\Big(\frac{2a(1-(2a)^n)}{n(1-2a)}\ln(b)}\Big)\leq1 $$

I try induction method but I have not a well evaluation of one of the term .

I try also to factorize with the formula :

$$e^{ix}+e^{iy}=2\cos(\frac{x-y}{2})e^{i\frac{x+y}{2}}$$ But I don't know if it's relevant here .

Maybe series expansion or Bernoulli's inequality can give something .

So if you can catch this problem ...

Thanks a lot for your time and patience .

Edit :
The case $n=2$

Since the function (where $0\leq x \leq 1$ and $a+b=1$ and $a,b>0$):

$$f(x)=a^{4b^2(1-x)+2bx}+b^{4a^2(1-x)+2ax}$$

Is convex we have by Jensen's inequality :

$$f(0)+f(1)\geq 2f(0.5)$$

Or :

$$a^{4b^2}+b^{4a^2}+a^{2b}+b^{2a}\geq 2(a^{2b^2+b}+b^{2a^2+a})$$

But $2\geq a^{4b^2}+b^{4a^2}+a^{2b}+b^{2a}$ because 
[If $a+b=1$ so $a^{4b^2}+b^{4a^2}\leq1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176571/if-ab-1-so-a4b2b4a2-leq1?noredirect=1&lq=1)
And if $a,b>0$ and $a+b=1$ then $1\geq a^{2b}+b^{2a}$
https://eudml.org/doc/223938

And we are done .

For the general case maybe one can use [Cauchy induction](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Induction)