# A Turan-type inequality :$\Big(a^{(2b)^n}-b^{(2a)^n}\Big)^2\geq \Big(a^{(2b)^{n-1}}-b^{(2a)^{n-1}}\Big)\Big(a^{(2b)^{n+1}}-b^{(2a)^{n+1}}\Big)$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, alternative-proof, jensen-inequality

Hi inspired by this question [Prove that if $a+b =1$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a^{(2b)^{n}} + b^{(2a)^{n}} \leq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198645/prove-that-if-ab-1-then-forall-n-in-mathbbn-a2bn-b2a?noredirect=1&lq=1) I propose this :

> > Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
> >     $$\Big(a^{(2b)^n}-b^{(2a)^n}\Big)^2\geq \Big(a^{(2b)^{n-1}}-b^{(2a)^{n-1}}\Big)\Big(a^{(2b)^{n+1}}-b^{(2a)^{n+1}}\Big)$$ 
> >     Where $n\geq 2$ a natural number .

It's [Turan-type inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_inequalities) of the form :

$$\operatorname{P_n}^2(x)\geq \operatorname{P_{n-1}}(x)\operatorname{P_{n+1}}(x)$$

My work :

The trick : Since $g(x)=\ln\Big(|a^{(2b)^{x\pm 1}}-b^{(2a)^{x\pm 1}}|\Big)$ I guess (by a numerical routine)that $g(x)$ is concave $\forall x\in [2,\infty)$ and remains to apply the Jensen's inequality to get the desired result .

Implicit question :

How to prove that the function $g(x)$ is [concave](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second%20derivative%20ln%28%7C%28a%5E%28%282%28b%29%29%5E%28x-1%29%29-%28b%29%5E%28%282*a%29%5E%28x-1%29%29%29%7C%29%20) or have you an other way ?

Any helps is greatly appreciated .

Thanks a lot for your contributions !

Comment: *“Since $g(x)$ ... is concave”* ... *“How to prove that $g(x)$ is concave?”*

Comment: @MartinR I assume this fact .Other questions ?

Comment: Then formulate it as an assumption (or guess), not as a statement. And please let us know *why* you think that $g$ is concave.

Comment: @MartinR by numerical routine obviously...