# Solve : $\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}+\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{b^n2^{n-1}}\leq 1 $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, exponentiation

> Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ and $n\geq 2$ a natural number then we have :

$$\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}+\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{b^n2^{n-1}}\leq 1 $$
We have here [Prove that if $a+b =1$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a^{(2b)^{n}} + b^{(2a)^{n}} \leq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198645/prove-that-if-ab-1-then-forall-n-in-mathbbn-a2bn-b2a?noredirect=1&lq=1) where users discuss about an upper bound
I remark that there is an interval $I=[\alpha,1]$ such that :

$$\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}\leq b^{(2a)^{n}}$$
And :
$$\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{b^n2^{n-1}}\leq a^{(2b)^{n}}$$

Because it's equivalent to :
$$\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)\leq a^{2}$$

Or :

$$\frac{a}{b}\leq a^{2a}+b^{2b}$$

By convexity of $x^{2x}$ and Jensen's inequality we have :

$$1\leq a^{2a}+b^{2b}$$

Remains to show :

$$\frac{a}{b}\leq 1$$ wich proves one of the two inequalities .

For small $n$ we can use Bernoulli's inequality .

Another try :

> Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ and $n\geq 2$ a natural number then we have :

$$\sin^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg)+\sin^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{b^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg)\leq 1 $$

A bit of algebra shows that it's equivalent to the initial inequality .

Moreover :

$$\sin^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg)+\sin^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{b^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg)\leq \sin^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg)+\cos^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg) $$

Or :
$$\sin^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{b^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg)\leq \cos^2\Bigg(\Bigg(\frac{ab}{a^{2a}+b^{2b}}\Bigg)^{a^n2^{n-1}}\Bigg) $$

Wich have the form :

$$\sin^2\Big(\beta^{b^n2^{n-1}}\Big)\leq \cos^2\Big(\beta^{a^n2^{n-1}}\Big)$$

Maybe for this last inequality we can use Taylor series and compare the coefficients .

Any helps is appreciated .

Thanks a lot for all your contributions .