# Final version about a problem due to Vasile Cirtaoje

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, exponential-function

### *Problem* :

Let $0<x<1$ and $k\geq 1$ then we have :

### $$x^{(2(1-x))^{k}}+(1-x)^{(2x)^{k}}\leq 1$$

*My strategy or sketch of a proof :*

### Part one the case $0<x\leq 0.25$

Using Bernoulli's inequality we have :

$$(1-x)^{(2x)^{k}}\leq 1-x(2x)^k$$

So we need to show :

$$x^{(2(1-x))^{k}}\leq x(2x)^k$$

We can finish it using derivatives .

### Part two the case $k\geq 1+\alpha$ :

We define $\alpha$ as :

$$\lim_{x\to 0.5^-}=\frac{\ln\Big(2(2^{2x}x^2(1-x)2)\Big)}{\ln(2x)}=\frac{\ln\Big(2(1-(2^{2x}x^2(1-x)2))\Big)}{\ln(2(1-x))}=\alpha=1.69315\cdots$$

We have :

$$x^{2(1-x)}\leq2^{2x}(1-x)2x^2$$

And :

$$(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1-2^{2x}(1-x)2x^2$$

For a sketch of proof see [Refinements of the inequality $f(x)=x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\leq 1$ for $0<x<0.5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853868/refinements-of-the-inequality-fx-x21-x1-x2x-leq-1-for-0x0-5)

So we have :

$$x^{(2(1-x))^k}\leq f(x)^{(2(1-x))^{k-1}}=(2^{2x}(1-x)2x^2)^{(2(1-x))^{k-1}}$$

And :

$$(1-x)^{(2x)^k}\leq (1-2^{2x}(1-x)2x^2)^{(2x)^{k-1}}$$

Now we want $y\geq 1$ a real number :

$$(2x)^{k-1}\geq (2f(x))^{y}$$
And
$$(2(1-x))^{k-1}\geq (2(1-f(x)))^{y}$$

Solving this we have

$$\frac{\ln\Big(2(1-(2^{2x}x^2(1-x)2))\Big)}{\ln(2(1-x))}\leq \frac{k-1}{y}\leq \frac{\ln\Big(2(2^{2x}x^2(1-x)2)\Big)}{\ln(2x)}\quad (1)$$

The constraint $(1)$ is honoured if :$$\alpha=\frac{k-1}{y}$$

So we have :

$$x^{(2(1-x))^k}\leq (f(x))^{(2(1-f(x))^{\frac{k-1}{\alpha}} }\quad (2)$$

And :

$$(1-x)^{(2x)^k}\leq (1-f(x))^{(2f(x))^{\frac{k-1}{\alpha}}}\quad (3)$$

Adding $(2)$ and $(3)$ we have :

$$h(k)\leq (1-f(x))^{(2f(x))^{\frac{k-1}{\alpha}}}+(f(x))^{(2(1-f(x))^{\frac{k-1}{\alpha}}}$$

We can repeat the reasoning $p$ times ($p\geq 1$ a natural number) and the last exponent becomes :

$$1\leq \frac{k-1}{\alpha^p}\leq \alpha$$

It's true because we can always choose $k$ such that :

$$\alpha^p\leq k \leq \alpha^{p+1}$$

So we reduce this case to the case $1\leq k\leq 1+\alpha $

### Part 3 the case $k\leq 1+\alpha $ and $0.25<x\leq 0.5$

Recently user RiverLi showed the lemma :

Lemma

Let $1< x$ and $a>2$ then we have :

$$r(x)=\left(1+\frac{\left(\ln\left(ax\right)^{c}-\ln\left(a\right)^{c}\right)}{\left(\ln\left(2a\right)^{c}-\ln\left(a\right)^{c}\right)}-x\right)\leq 0$$

We can find $c$ as $r'(2)=0$.

We cannot apply it directly but it's possible with the new form :

$$\left(x^{-(2(1-x))^{k}}-1\right)\left((1-x)^{-(2x)^{k}}-1\right)\geq 1$$

Now we apply twice the  lemma and we start by introducing (see the reference) :

$$f(k)=((\ln((a)x^{-(2(1-x))^k}))^c-(\ln(a))^c) ((\ln((a)(1-x)^{-(2(x))^k}))^c-(\ln(a))^c)$$

Conjecture :

Let $a=10^{10}$ in $f(k)$ then the function $g(k),h(k)$ are log convex always with the contraint above where :

$$g(k)=((\ln((a)x^{-(2(1-x))^k}))^c-(\ln(a))^c) $$

And

$$l(k)=((\ln((a)(1-x)^{-(2(x))^k}))^c-(\ln(a))^c)$$

So it reduces to the case $k=1$ wich is the hardest here with the new form .

### *Two questions :*

1)Is it good I mean nothing wrong here ?

2)How to show the missing parts especially the case $k=1$ where I used the lemma ?

Thanks you!

Reference:

[1] Vasile Cirtoaje, "Proofs of three open inequalities with power-exponential functions",
The Journal of Nonlinear Sciences and its Applications (2011), Volume: 4, Issue: 2, page 130-137.
https://eudml.org/doc/223938

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1029-242X-2013-468

[Prove or disprove: $1+\frac{\ln^c(ax)-\ln^ca}{\ln^c(2a)-\ln^ca}-x\leq 0$, where $1<x$, $a>2$, and $c$ is chosen so that $f'(2)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188569/prove-or-disprove-1-frac-lncax-lnca-lnc2a-lnca-x-leq-0-where/4206969?noredirect=1#comment8734866_4206969)