# inequality $\Re\Bigg(\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2a))}{\ln(2a)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{a}}+\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2b))}{\ln(2b)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{b}}\Bigg)<1$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, exponentiation, lambert-w, power-towers

Problem inspired by Vasile Cirtoaje :

> Let $0<b<0.5<a<1$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :

$$\Re\Bigg(\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2a))}{\ln(2a)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{a}}+\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2b))}{\ln(2b)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{b}}\Bigg)<1$$

Where we speak about the Lambert's function and the real part of a complex number .

Well first of all we have in other word :

$$(2a)^{(2a)^{(2a)\cdots}}=\frac{W(-\ln(2a))}{-\ln(2a)}$$

I have tried to prove something like :

$\exists x \quad $$0<x<0.5$ such that :
$$\Re\Bigg(\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2x))}{\ln(2x)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{x}}\Bigg)<x$$

And

$\exists x \quad $$0.5<x<1$ such that :
$$\Re\Bigg(\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2x))}{\ln(2x)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{x}}\Bigg)<x$$

I have tried also an approximation with some parabola or :

$\exists x \quad $$0.5<x<1$ such that :
$$\Re\Bigg(\Bigg(1-\frac{W(-\ln(2x))}{\ln(2x)}\Bigg)^{1-\frac{1}{x}}\Bigg)<ax^2+bx+c$$

Without success because due to the divergence I don't know how to deal with the real part .

A relevant problem is [If $0<a<1, 0<b<1$, $a+b=1$, then prove that $a^{2b}+ b^{2a} \le 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395858/if-0a1-0b1-ab-1-then-prove-that-a2b-b2a-le-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Well if you have a way or something plausible feel free to make comments/answers .

Thanks in advance !